# libvirt : Host - Guest can't get the correct route to make both pingable

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, libvirt

I'am runing A Ubuntu server as a Host, and I've a CentOS guest hosting an oracle database.

Everything was working just fine, until someone init 6 the server (What a great idea!). So I've to reconfigure again the Host-Guest route, but I totaly forgot what I did to get everything working...

Normaly on my Guest I just have to run a .sh  :

```
ifconfig eth0 10.0.45.100/32 up
route add -host 188.165.***.*** dev eth0
route add default gw 188.165.***.***
ip route add default dev eth0
```

But now I've to find what I did on the Host to route correctly everything

I found this post : [How to bridge a range of public IPs to KVM virtual machines on Debian/Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/409451/how-to-bridge-a-range-of-public-ips-to-kvm-virtual-machines-on-debian-ubuntu)

I've a bridge br0 and my guest's interface is vnet0 so I tried

```
ip addr add 10.0.45.100/32 dev br0
```

But that's route 10.0.45.100 to the host and not the guest (I tired dev vnet0 just in case) but it's not working either.

So at the moment, my host can't ping my guest, and my guest can't ping my host :/
if you have anyideas let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add this route :

```
ip route add to 10.0.45.100/32 dev br0
```

And now everything is working just fine.